# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Min(Int32, Int32)'?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Im getting this error when I execute the following code, any Ideas how to fix it?

---

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Min(Int32, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

---

```
result = items.ToList()
                    .Select(b => new BatchToWorkOnModel()
                    {
                        BatchID = b.Batch.ID,
                        SummaryNotes = b.Batch.Notes,
                        RowVersion = b.Batch.RowVersion,
                        Items = items
                            .Select(i => new ItemToWorkOnModel()
                            {
                                SupplierTitle = i.Title,
                                ItemID = i.ID,
                                BatchID = i.BatchID ?? 0,
                                ItemDate = i.PubDate,
                                // KB - Issue 276 - Return the correct Outlet name for each item
                                Outlet = i.Items_SupplierFields != null ? i.Items_SupplierFields.SupplierMediaChannel != null ? i.Items_SupplierFields.SupplierMediaChannel.Name : null : null,
                                Status = ((short)ItemStatus.Complete == i.StatusID ? "Done" : "Not done"),
                                NumberInBatch = i.NumInBatch,
                                Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Body) ? "" : i.Body.Substring(0, Math.Min(i.Body.Length, 50)) + (i.Body.Length < 50 ? "" : "..."),
                                IsRelevant = i.IsRelevant == 1,
                                PreviouslyCompleted = i.PreviouslyCompleted > 0 ? true : false
                            }).ToList()
                    })
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Math.Min is not implemented by the EF query provider. You should be able to fix it by simply applying `AsEnumerable` on your items collection to do the expression using Linq to Objects instead;

```
Items = items.AsEnumerable().Select(i => new ItemToWorkOnModel()...
```

If you add a `where` condition to the item selection (seems a little strange to take all items in the whole table), you'll want to add it before AsEnumerable() to allow EF to do the filtering in the database.

Also, you only want the first result from the query, but you're fetching *all* of them using `ToList()` before cutting the list down to a single item. You may want to remove the `ToList()` so that EF/the underlying database can return only a single result;

```
result = items.Select(b => new BatchToWorkOnModel()...
```

Comment: I agree with you in principle. However having a second look at the source. Given the number of `.ToList()` we should be running LinqToObject rather than LinqToEF. I am not sure that the source code is correct...

Comment: @Aron The first ToList() in the main query won't affect the subquery (it'll basically just fetch the whole table into a List), and the subquery contains ToList() _after_ all of the selection has been done, so it'll use Linq to Entities for the querying/projection.

Comment: I noticed that the child property would likely not be loaded, and hence would produce a n+1 query. However I figured that (depending on implementation) the property was likely implemented as a `List<>`. This would suggest that the child list is fetched by Lazy Loading, as opposed to an explicit EF query. Again, the result is a projection on a List, rather than a DbSet/DbQuery/ObjectSet/ObjectQuery.

Comment: @Aron I'm not sure I understand what property you're talking about that's implemented as a `List<>` :)

Comment: I'm not sure if your suggestion not to use ToList() is a good one. Of course EF will only fetch a single row but in the inner query all items will be loaded anyway. So the use of ToList to load everything in the first place might actually be a good idea this time.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `Math.Min`.

The line in question is:

```
Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Body)
       ? "" : i.Body.Substring(0, Math.Min(i.Body.Length, 50)) + (i.Body.Length < 50 ? "" : "...")
```

So what does this line return?

If `i.Body` is null or empty it returns an empty string. If it is 50 or more characters long it returns a substring of 50 characters and appends "...".
If the length is less than 50 it takes a substring with the length of the string and appends an empty string. But that's just the original string.

```
Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Body)
       ? "" : (i.Body.Length < 50 ? i.Body : i.Body.Substring(0, 50) + "...")
```